# How enable MrSID in Geoserver 2.9.2 [Oracle Linux Server]

Tags: geoserver, gdal, mrsid

On same server there are 3 Tomcats and each Tomcat has a geoserver application running on it. For some reason 2 geoservers pickup MrSID and other extensions while 1 goeserver does not. Where should I look in the configurations to enable MrSID and other extensions. All geoservers have same .jars in WEB-INF/lib.

**EDIT**: After geoserver restart MrSID and other coverage formats appeard in the store creation window. I have done nothing to fix it. Miracle!

**Note:** I have no access to the server logs so won't be asking for them anymore (already asked couple of times!!!) therefore can not give anyone more info about this issue. Also I am certain that this geoserver was restarted several times in the past, so maybe after previous restart something went wrong...

Comment: Look for WARN or ERROR messages in `geoserver.log` when starting tomcat and post it here.
Off-Topic: Be aware that GeoServer 2.9.x is not maintained anymore. Current stable version is 2.11.

Answer (score 1):

MrSid does not have configurations to be enabled, it requires two things:

- The GDAL extension jars in web-inf/lib (you say you have them already)
- The custom GDAL native libraries shipped by GeoServer in LD_LIBRARY_PATH (which I'm guessing maybe you have on two servers, but not on the third?), and not the operating system native GDAL package instead

Comment: Where LD_LIBRARY_PATH  should be set in geoserver configurations? I have no access to two correctly working geoserver but I have seen their setenv's and there was no LD_LIBRARY_PATH.

Comment: LD_LIBRARY_PATH is not a GeoServer configuration variable, it's a Linux system environment variable influencing the lookup of dynamic link libraries: http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/shared-libraries.html

Comment: I understant that. I imagine that this variablie should be set specifically for the geoserver that is giving me the trouble: either in it's Tomcat setenv.sh, other Tomcat configuratin or somewhere in geoservers configs. I got this idea because of "shipped by GeoServer in LD_LIBRARY_PATH (which I'm guessing maybe you have on two servers, but not on the third?)". Or am I wrong?

Comment: So the question would be how do I ship custom GDAL native libraries via LD_LIBRARY_PATH to my troublesome geoserver?

Comment: In the script that launches Tomcat (which depends on how it's installed, distribution and the like) you can add "export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/path/to/gdal/libs:%LD_LIBRARY_PATH%"